# How to deal with the removal of offline_access when managing a page?

Tags: facebook, offline, deprecated, access-token, facebook-access-token

Now that [offline_access has been removed](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/), I'm wondering how I should set up my app. Here's an overview of my app as I want it to work:

- A first user, *admin*, logs in first, makes a facebook page and starts building a followers list.
- Other facebook users, *others*, find the page, and log in as well
- The *admin* can choose from the *others* a few to give them more rights, they become *moderators*.

<sub>NB: it is assumed this group of people know each other outside facebook and the internet. Also, the *admin* pays for this system.</sub>

The system with this user role model has to publish to the page of the *admin*. This might happen when the *admin* is signed in or not, it could also happen when an other user is logged in or when a cronjob is called.

I need this system to continue to work even after the 2-month access token of the *admin* expires, otherwise the facebook page would go cold. How can I make sure that doesn't happen?

The only thing I can think of is keeping track of the expiration date of the access tokens and mailing (automatically) or calling when an *admin* doesn't sign in for 1.5 month. Is that the recommended way to do this? Are there other things I should consider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your case here, instead of using admin's extended access token you may use the same (extended access token) to retrieve the page access token from the

```
me/accounts
```

endpoint which will return the never expiring page access token for the page your *admin* wants to administer and use the same for the purpose of posting/sharing on the Page's wall.